# Unit Testing Azure Functions that user property binding

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions

I've created some functions and have used this post https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/azure-functions-binding-to-a-property/ to create them using custom properties

I set up the test project and files using the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function

My question is, how can functions that use property binding be unit tested? as all the examples I've looked at online use the test factory class to pass in a type of httpRequest.

```
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] GetStudyDetailsRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new ArtenaServiceClient(ArtenaServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IArtenaService);
            var result = await client.GetStudyDetailsAsync(req.StudentID, req.Dev);
            return CreateActionResult.Create(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError(e, "", req);
            return new OkObjectResult(new { e.Message, e.StackTrace });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create the necessary input and pass them to the function to test the expected behavior. Like any other unit test. The factory class is for grouping boiler plate code together for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I won't need to include Azure Function request property binding in my "unit" test scope firstly because that's not part of my code I am calling a unit here, secondly that's not my code at all :). That kind of testing might be relevant for end to end integration test where you would send http request to a running Function app. So, here in this case, I would just treat the function `Run` method as a regular C# method by passing required input directly from unit test.